# Quantum state are uncountable infinite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, mathematics

Take energy eigenstates of an electron of a hydrogen atom ( just for example ) are infinite. I am just wondering:

1. are they countably infinite?
2. or are they uncountable infinite?
   While looking at the formulation, it looks like they are countable infinite because we are using a $n \in \mathbb{N} $ while writing it down. It's a formulation. If they are uncountable infinite, then with this $n$, we can't label all the states.

Since the spectrum can be countable or uncountable infinite, is there any experimental verification that they are with either of these?

Comment: 1. How would one ever "experimentally verify" whether some set is countably or uncountably infinite, when experiments by their very nature only ever produce finite data sets? 2. What problem do you have in figuring out whether the energy eigenstates of the hydrogen atom are countable? They're indexed by natural numbers!

Comment: @ACuriousMind well,  the bound states have $n, l\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ . The unbound states have $l,m$ but $k_r$ is on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind why do you have such a negative attitude towards this question?  It's a funny pattern that you pounce on and downvote all these genuine questions by people curious about physics without a physics background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the specific quantum system you are looking at, there is no general principle in the standard framework of quantum mechanics as to whether the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian (or any other operator for that matter) ought to be finite in number, countably infinite, or uncountably infinite.

We can give simple examples for each of the cases:

- The energy spectrum of a two-level system is finite, it has only two energy eigenstates.
- The energy spectrum of the simple harmonic oscillator is countably infinite, one can label the eigenstates with a discrete label $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.
- The energy spectrum of a free particle on a line is uncountably infinite, it can only be labeled by a continuous real variable $p\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\cup\{0\}$.

Similarly, one can find examples for the spectrum of other operators. The basic idea is that how many eigenstates the spectrum of an observable has depends on the structure (in particular, the dimensionality) of the Hilbert space in which the state vector that describes a quantum system lives. The general principles of quantum mechanics do not fix the dimensionality of the Hilbert space.

Finally, obviously, you can never give a positive experimental verification that something is infinite. What we do is experimentally verify that a particular model for a quantum system produces predictions that can be experimentally tested and if this model has a Hamiltonian that has a spectrum consisting of an infinite (either countable or uncountable) number of eigenstates then we say that the system's energy spectrum consists of an infinite (countable or uncountable) number of energy eigenstates.

Comment: surely the h.o. is not countably *finite* but countably *infinite*…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Haha, of course! Uncountably finite would have been even more interesting. ;) Corrected.

Comment: Statistical mechanics makes different predictions between a physical system with countably infinite states versus a system with uncountably infinite states.